# Dissolving black screen with help of javascript or jquery in HTML Page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want that, while loading my page, there should be a black screen with white letters on it. And after 3 seconds it must dissolve and main page will be visible.

How can I do it with either JavaScript or jQuery ?

Comment: Create a div and use setTimeout to hide it. But you need to tell us if you have tried anything? And post your HTML and JQ code as well.

Answer (score 1):

Let's imagine that your black screen is div with id 'black-screen'

```
 <div id="black-screen">
      <!-- Black screen and white letters goes here -->
 </div>
```

Somewhere in your document put

```
<script>
    function hideBlackScreen(){
        $("#black-screen").hide('slow');
    }
    $(function(){
        setTimeout(hideBlackScreen, 3000);
    });
</script>
```

I can post some jsfiddle example if You want

Here is jQuery Docs on hide() function [link](http://api.jquery.com/hide/)

Comment: If You found my answer helpful, i would appreciate You to accept it :)

Answer (score 1):

First you need an HTML structure that's suited to the task. A content container and an overlay container as siblings work well for this purpose.

**Example HTML**

```
<div id="overlay">
    <p>Please wait while something wonderful happens</p>
</div>
<div id="content">
    <div id="lipsum">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

To do it with jQuery, hide your content container initially and use the built-in `.fadeOut` method. Make sure to supply a callback that shows your content container when finished. Here's an example:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var showContent = function showContent() {
        //callback that fires once animation is complete.
        $('#content').show();
    }, hideOverlay = function hideOverlay() {
        $('#overlay').fadeOut('slow', showContent);
    };
    //after 3000 milliseconds (=3 seconds), call the hideOverlay function
    window.setTimeout(hideOverlay, 3000);
});
```

**JavaScript**

To do it with plain-old JavaScript, you'll need to adjust the `opacity` style of the element over time (`window.setInterval` is your friend here.) Here's an example:

```
window.onload = function () {
    var JSShowContent = function JSShowContent() {
        var content = document.getElementById('content');
        content.style.display = 'block';
    }, JSHideOverlay = function JSHideOverlay () {
        var overlay = document.getElementById('overlay'),
            opacity = 1,
            interval = 0,
            rate = 5; //rate is in milliseconds
        overlay.style.opacity = opacity; //set initial opacity as it defaults to ""
        interval = window.setInterval(function () {
            opacity -= 0.01; //decrement opacity
            overlay.style.opacity = opacity;
            if (opacity <= 0) {
                window.clearInterval(interval);
                overlay.style.display = 'none';
                JSShowContent();
            }
        } , rate);
    };
    //after 3000 milliseconds (=3 seconds), call the hideOverlay function
    window.setTimeout(JSHideOverlay, 3000);
};
```

**Live Demo**

Here's a fiddle you can play with: http://jsfiddle.net/dYrsP/

Simply change the function in `window.setTimeout` to `hideOverlay` and re-run it to see the jQuery version.

Answer (score 0):

To have a fullscreen div:

http://andrewpeace.com/css-full-screen-div.html

```
<body style="height:100%">
<div style="width:100%;height:100%;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;left:0;
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 black;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;">
    <font style="color:white">My text</font>
</div>
```